# Firebase issue. dSym files. "Customers with bitcode-enabled..."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, dsym

After uploading the new version of the IOS application, a window appeared on Firebase that you need to upload dSym files. I have uploaded them. The window is gone. But now the following window appeared on the dSym tab:

"Customers with bitcode-enabled apps have reported that some dSYMs required for crash reporting are not available for download on App Store Connect. This may prevent crashes from appearing on the dashboard. We are looking into this issue."

Does anyone know what could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

When the build is uploaded using BitCode Enabled option, the dysm file needs to be updated manually for each build.

Firebase needs to solve this issue.

[image]